# finding the solution to $(I_3+A)x=b+2x$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble solving the $(I_3+A)x=b+2x$ without finding the matrix $A$.

you are also given the inverse of $A$ and the matrix $b$ which consist of 3x1.

Comment: Could you provide for us the inverse of $A$ and also the matrix $b$ so that we can better answer your question?

Comment: A inverse is  $ \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $   and b is  $ \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix} $

Answer (score 1):

The equation $(I_3+A)x=b+2x$ can be turned into $$(I_3+A-2I_3)x=b\\(A-I_3)x=b$$
So you just need to solve for this matrix system:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}A_{11}-1&A_{12}&A_{13}&b_1\\A_{21}&A_{22}-1&A_{23}&b_2\\A_{31}&A_{32}&A_{33}-1&b_3\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Check your work. $I-2I\neq-2I$.